# grails codenarc "Error Script not found: Codenarc"

Tags: grails, jenkins, codenarc

I want to run codenarc on our jenkins it always fails and all I get in the output is

```
$ /opt/grails/bin/grails -Dgrails.work.dir=/var/lib/jenkins/.grails-codenarc codenarc --non-interactive
| Loading Grails 2.4.4
| Configuring classpath
| Running pre-compiled script
| Error Script not found: Codenarc
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure
```

Of course I included it in the BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
   build ":tomcat:$tomcatVersion"

   compile ':codenarc:0.22'
   ...
}
```

Also, when I run it on the server within a bash as the jenkins user, it works perfectly and is creating the expected output files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the build does a clean checkout you need to run `grails compile` before running any scripts to ensure the plugins are installed